# difference between OODBMS, ORDBMS, Network Model, Hierarchical model

Tags: rdbms, database, object-oriented-database

can any one describe the exact difference between dbms models.. i have gone through many papers but im still confused between these.. 
his approach to DBMS is more flexible than the hierarchical approach, but still the programmer has to know the physical representation of data to be able to access it, and accordingly applications using a network database has to be changed every time the structure of the database changes.